# How to animate closing NSWindow to NSStatusItem?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsstatusitem

When you minimize an `NSWindow` you get a nice animation to the Dock. How to achieve a similar animation for "minimizing" to an `NSStatusItem` in the menu bar?

I have it set up where the `NSStatusItem` appears when you close the `NSWindow` but there is no animation.

I've tried animating the window frame but due to various layout contraints it has a minimum size that gets in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate the whole NSWindow is not the right way and will result in a rubbish looking animation. I would suggest to capture a snapshot of the window and adding it to a transparent full screen window to animate layer of the image view. This way its fare more smooth. To get an idea how it could be implemented please take a look at this [project on git](https://github.com/jwilling/JNWAnimatableWindow).

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The window to dock "genie" effect is a fake animation.

Comment: Is the transparent full screen window necessary though? Sounds like a hack with potential side effects.

Comment: Like Oskar said, Apple as well is doing it like this.

Comment: Do you know if JNWAnimatableWindow is allowed for apps in the Mac App Store?

Comment: I had an app in the Mac App Store using the same technique to flip a window. I was never using JNWAnimatableWindow but it should  be a good source on how it can be done. I also found another resource on how to animate NSWindow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517386/how-to-give-nswindow-a-shake-effect-as-saying-no-as-in-login-failure-window/36006764#36006764. Maybe this is easier to implement and it already fit your requirement. But as mentioned with the Layer technique its possible to make it more smooth and with a transformation.